# Classification of line bundles by group homomorphisms from the fundamental group to $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, vector-bundles, fundamental-groups, classifying-spaces

Let $X$ be a path-connected manifold. Then by the classification of vector bundles, the collection of all (real) line bundles on $X$ is
$$
\text{Vect}^1(X)\cong [X,BO(1)]=[X,\mathbb{R}P^\infty]=[X,B\mathbb{Z}_2]
$$
where $\mathbb{Z}_2=\{\pm 1\}$ under multiplication.

**Question.**  Are there any results/references giving that

$$
\text{Vect}^1(X)\cong \text{Hom}(\pi_1(X), \mathbb{Z}_2)?
$$
Whether can we just take loop space
$$
[X,B\mathbb{Z}_2]=[\Omega X,\Omega B\mathbb{Z}_2] =[\pi_1(X), \mathbb{Z}_2]
$$
or not?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277823/tautological-line-bundle-over-mathbbrpn-isomorphic-to-normal-bundle-also/1277969#1277969 and note that $H^1(X;A)= Hom(\pi_1 X,A)$ if $A$ is abelian.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general,

$$[X, K(G, n)] \cong H^n(X; G)$$

where $K(G, n)$ is an [Eilenbeg-MacLane space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93MacLane_space) (see Theorem $4.57$ of Hatcher's [*Algebraic Topology*](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf)).

In particular, if $G$ is equipped with the discrete topology, then [$BG$ is a $K(G, 1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1871555/39599) so

$$[X, BG] \cong [X, K(G, 1)] \cong H^1(X; G).$$

On the other hand, for an *abelian* group $G$,

$$H^1(X; G) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(X), G).$$

This isomorphism follows from the Universal Coefficient Theorem for cohomology (see the argument given in the first paragraph of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1154136/39599) which uses $G = \mathbb{Z}$, but will work for any abelian group $G$).

Therefore,

$$\operatorname{Vect}^1(X) \cong [X, B\mathbb{Z}_2] \cong H^1(X; \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(X), \mathbb{Z}_2).$$

Note, none of the above required $X$ to be a manifold.

Comment: Thanks! How to obtain the last isomorphism?

Comment: I have added some references.

Comment: Very clear and didactic answer:+1